# How to idempotently define row-level security policies in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently learned about row-level security policies in SQL, and love the idea of being able to run important security logic inside the database. However, I'm not sure how to make the workflow for updating RLS policies as good as updating API code is.

Since RLS policies are essentially just stateless logic, it feels like I should be able to define them all in an sql schema file that is checked into git and run on each deploy to idempotently set the policies.

We can get some of the way there by using `drop if exists`, e.g.:

```sql
drop policy if exists "everyone can read" on patterns;
create policy "everyone can read" on patterns for select using (auth.role() = 'anon');
```

This seems pretty good, but it's not quite truly declarative, because it won't drop any policies that still exist in the database from a previous version of the schema. Can I drop all existing policies for a table and then recreate them? Or is there another way to go about this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want to get rid of a policy, the only thing you need to do is to include the `drop policy if exists` line, but don't add the `create policy` line.

Comment: Yep, but to be sure it syncs correctly, I'd have to keep a drop statement in the file for every policy that had ever existed in any version of the database. It works but a bit messy, I figured out how to query for existing policies instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- query [`pg_policy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-policy.html) for all policies on a table and drop them
- drop all policies that ever existed in any version of your schema

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to drop all policies. There are two catalog tables that list policies; `pg_policy` has low-level info, whereas `pg_policies` is more useful for this because it includes the table names directly.

```sql
-- Drop all existing policies
do
$$
declare
   rec record;
begin
   for rec in (SELECT tablename, policyname FROM pg_policies)
   loop
     execute 'drop policy "'||rec.policyname||'" on '||rec.tablename;
   end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: You should use [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) for proper escaping though. Also don't ignore the schema name of the table. `SELECT polname AS name, polrelid::regclass AS table FROM pg_policy` and `EXECUTE format('DROP POLICY %i ON %s, pol.name, pol.table);`