# PostgreSQL idempotent Policy row level se

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

In SQL you can perform a

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (... table definition);
```

which allows you to run the same SQL multiple times without it erroring.

With policies you use:

```
CREATE policy "Users can read their own profile"  
  on user_profiles for insert with check ( auth.uid() = user_id );
```

However running this command more than once will result in an error like:

> policy "Users can read their own profile" for table "user_profiles" already exists

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html), conditional policy creation does not seem to be an option.  Is there any way around this?

Note there is [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024643/how-to-idempotently-define-row-level-security-policies-in-postgresql) which claims that there is already a idempotent policy creation.  I would argue this is not the case.  Running `drop policy if exists "Users can read their own profile" on user_profiles;` followed by the create seems error prone unless it's possible to perform this inside a transaction which I don't know if that's possible.  i.e. if your script partially ran it would leave your application without a policy applied after it previously had been applied.

Comment: DDL can be run in a transaction, so you can run the `drop policy` and `create policy` in a single transaction as well.

Comment: "...which I don't know if that's possible", how hard would it have been to verify this on your own?

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name , if you wanted to post that as an answer I will accept it.  I had never heard of DDL before you had written that despite reading the docs on it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-rowsecurity.html

Comment: @AdrianKlaver good question.  I did try to find out but my searching didn't yield anything: https://www.google.com/search?q=run+postgres+drop+create+policy+in+transaction  Once I knew the answer and was introduced to the concept of DDL from a_horse_with_no_name 's comment then I could find it: https://www.google.com/search?q=run+postgres+ddl+in+transaction here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462475/is-it-possible-to-wrap-ddl-changes-in-a-transaction-in-postgresql

Comment: All that instead of just trying:`BEGIN; CREATE POLICY ...; DROP POLICY...; COMMIT OR ROLLBACK;`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have 10 says left on a large project that I after 1 month of wasted work I am having to change the backend on for postgres.  I am very short on time and very stressed.  I could not find anything when I searched.  The approach you have suggested is not watertight as I can't break the db connection to supabase.io exactly at the moment after the drop, before the create.  You sound creative and smart and if you imagine what others may be experiencing, and what they may be able to do given their resources, you *may* more often find others less frustrating and perplexing.

Comment: I understand stress, more then you know. The purpose of my comments where to help with that. Instead of spending time looking for a perfect answer it is usually faster and easier to test solutions yourself. See this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGPAJNeyHVR1YTyjznAjTT/0).  It proves `DROP/CREATE POLICY` work in a transaction. If the `A` in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) does not work you have bigger issues then this particular case.  When starting a project I set up a test database locally to try things out to confirm behavior of just this sort of thing.